# nodejs на vps | ngix + nodejs + apache

Tags: node.js, apache

**Кратко**: как запустить nodejs на 80 порту, если на сервере стоит apache.

Создал веб приложение на `react`, настроил `ssr` (`nodejs` + `express`) и написал `api` для получения данных с бд на wordpress (`rest api`).

Но так как это мой первый проект с SSR и соответственно с запуском nodejs сервера на продакшене, то задался вопросом **"Как все это совместить?"**

Сайт расположен на name.ru, а `api` к нему на `backend.name.ru`. Для запуска express использую `pm2`, но только сайт запускается на 3000 порту, а мне, получается, нужен 80 и `apache` не "отдает" его. Нашел информацию, что мне может помочь ngix, но тогда его нужно настраивать для совместной работы с php, т.к. api на worpdress, который муторно запускать на ngix.

В общем сисадмин из меня никакой, а сайт нужно запустить, как обычно, вчера

Comment: надо сделать так, чтобы запросы на 80-й порт, apache перенаправлял на нодовский порт 3000. Как это сделать - я не знаю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Установил на сервер ngnix в добавок к apache и прописал конфиг из этой [инструкции](https://gist.github.com/tomasevich/a2fe588c451c5a192893e6521a813020) - заработало

```
# Настройка сервера
server {
    # Nginx слушает порт 80
    # default_server - указан в /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    listen 80 default_server;
    # Указываем "динамическую" папку NodeJS
    root /var/www/nodejs;
    # Указываем основной файл заглушки
    index index.html;
    # Устанавливаем страницы ошибок
    # В папке /var/www/errors должны быть файлы 
    # 50x.html и 40x.html соответственно
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    error_page 400 401 402 403 404 /40x.html;
    location = /50x.html { 
        root /var/www/errors;
    }
    location = /40x.html { 
        root /var/www/errors;
    }
    # Указываем IP адрес сервера
    server_name IP_адрес_сервера;
    # Если мы обращаемся по любому УРЛ начиная с /
    # то сервер будет обрабатывать NodeJS
    location / {
        # Тут указываем IP|Url и порт (8000) для NodeJS
        # поскольку Nginx будет висеть на 80 порту
        proxy_pass http://xn--iporurl__-7yhbxyobb6pdcob:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
    # Если мы обращемся по УРЛ начинающийся с /nginx/
    # то мы будем подгружать "статичные" файлы хранящиеся в нем
    # в соответствии с наличием этих файлов в этой папке
    location /nginx/ {
        # Указываем корень
        root /var/www/;
        autoindex off;
        # Итого путь для Nginx будет
        # /var/www/static/
    }
}
```